# Unwanted "Sticky" Tint at NavBar after back segues

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am getting a sticky solid tint underneath my VC1's navBar after I click `back` from VC2. On launch, I do not see this stickiness, only after clicking `back`. How do I remove this stickiness? Images as such.

NavBar in VC1 without stickiness, ie the white background stretches as I pull the navBar down:

[image: NavBar in VC1 without tint]

NavBar in VC1 with stickiness, ie the white background does not stretch as I pull the navBar down
[image: NavBar in VC1 with stickiness after clicking 'back' from VC2]

Code so far:

```
//At viewDidLoad() in VC1
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white


//At viewDidLoad() in VC2

navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

I have implemented like so in VC2 is because I have a mapView which I want to spread all the way up to the status bar.

Would anybody able to advice how do I remove the sticky tint such that the white tint stretches as I pull down the navBar in VC1?

Comment: try moving any UI related code to viewWillAppear

Comment: @Scriptable just tried, I've moved all codes in VC1 and VC2 to viewWillAppear but gave the same result

Answer (score 0):

The reason it happens on the back button is because the changes on the navigation bar made in VC2 also apply to the navigation bar of VC1.

You could try to fix it by moving the code to the viewWillAppear method and than adding the following lines to the VC1 code:

```
var navBarBackgroundImage: UIImage?
var navBarShadowImage: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navBarBackgroundImage = navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundImage(for: .default)
    navBarShadowImage = navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let navBarBackgroundImage = navBarBackgroundImage {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBarBackgroundImage, for: .default)
    }
    if let navBarShadowImage = navBarShadowImage {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = navBarShadowImage
    }
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
}
```

VC2:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

Comment: I just tried your method, but now VC1 gave a black background view instead when `back` button is pressed at VC2.